# Regex to match for multiple strings anywhere within a string

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I'm trying to add some validation in ASP.NET using Regex. Essentially I need to ensure a text box includes both ***ThisString*** and ***ThatString*** including the asterisks.

I can get it to work with one, or one or the other, just not both being present at the same time and at any part of the string.l it's validating.

Thanks

Comment: Not an optimal solution: `\*\*\*ThisString\*\*\*.*\*\*\*ThatString\*\*\*|\*\*\*ThatString\*\*\*.*\*\*\*ThisString\*\*\*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nanhydrin correctly pointed out, my solution will not work if there are multiple of one of the strings but not the other. If that case may occur, you can check for each string separately for readability's sake

- First regular expression- `(?:\*{3}ThisString\*{3})`
- Second regular expression- `(?:\*{3}ThatString\*{3})`

If matches are found in both cases, you're good to go!

### Original Answer:-

This is the regular expression you want: `(?:\*{3}(?:ThisString|ThatString)\*{3})`

**Note**: Make sure to have global match on and be sure to escape the asterisks correctly.

If the above expression finds 2 (or more) matches, it means you're good to go.

Explanation:-

- The entire thing is in a non capturing group, this is to ensure, everything within does get matched fully
- There are 3 stars on each side of the strings, having 3 stars on one side but not the other will **not** result in a match
- Both `ThisString` and `ThatString` are in a grouped alternative, this is to reduce clutter, you could totally jam every possible positional pattern but this is just better as position doesn't matter here. `***ThatString***` can come before `***ThisString***` or vice versa.

**MAKE SURE** to check the length of the matches found, the length must be 2 for your 
 described condition to be satisfied.

Here's the [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/g1ZYwU/1)

Comment: This will match text with two ThisStrings and no ThatString though (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks, I've added an answer which now seems to be working thanks to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using @Chase's answer I was able to come up with the following:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    Regex thisString = new Regex("(?:\*{3}ThisString\*{3})");
    Regex thatString = new Regex("(?:\*{3}ThatString\*{3})");

    if (!thisString.IsMatch(value.ToString()) || !thatString.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
    {
        return new ValidationResult("***ThisString*** and ***ThatString*** are used to generate the email text. Please ensure the text above has both ***ThisString*** and ***ThatString*** somewhere within the text.");        }

    return  ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Now if either regex patterns don't match anywhere, it'll return an error.